# Power BI DAX: Sum a column up to the current row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a the following structure :

```
 2 10/1/2019 
 1 10/12/2019
 0 10/13/2019
 3 11/1/2019
```

each row has a date and an integer assigned to the date. I want to create a column with the sum up to the date of the row: (like so)

```
2 10/1/2019 2
1 10/12/2019 3
0 10/13/2019 3
3 11/1/2019 6
```

this is the DAX I tried:

```
Count = 
    var ThisDate = Table[Date]
    var t = SUMX(FILTER(Table, Table[Date]<=ThisDate),[number])
return t
```

but the results Im getting are far off what I described, what is wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate function here:

```
Count = 
VAR ThisDate = Table[Date] 
RETURN 
        CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Number]),FILTER(Table,ThisDate >= Table[Date]))
```